# Disable dropdown list on certain condition at another dropdown list

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a simple webpage which looks like this;

[image]

The html code is as follow;

```
<div ng-controller="room_controller" class="md-padding" ng-cloak layout="column">
    <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">Room settings</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                <span>Room</span>
                <md-select ng-model="mode" placeholder="Mode1" class="md-no-underline">
                    <md-option value="auto">Mode1</md-option>
                    <md-option value="manual">Mode2</md-option>
                </md-select>
                <md-select ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
                    <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
                    <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
                    <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
                </md-select>
            </div>
        </md-card-content>
    <md-card>
</div>
```

The angularjs controller code looks something like this;

```
.controller('room_controller', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

    }])
```

I am using angularjs v1 materials. When the value inside dropdown list at the centre is `Mode1`, I want the dropdown list at the right to be disabled (user cannot click on it to choose). Otherwise, the dropdown list at the right is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this, add a ng-disabled directive

```
<md-select ng-disabled="mode == 'auto'" ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
    <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
    <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you update your answer to use `ng-disabled`?
user8461258 pointed out this syntax error. Other than that, your answer is perfect. I would like to mark your answer as the answer since you are earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `ng-disabled` directive. Change this line of your code;

```
<md-select ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
```

to this line;

```
<md-select ng-disabled="mode == 'auto'" ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
```

Jihin Raju's is almost correct except for a syntax error (`ng-disabled`, not `ng-disable`).